# How to overcome the "element not interactable exception"

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQRvh.png)

I have tried double click method, Thread.sleep, implicit wait , explicit wait(both before and after the element), used xpath, css locators but I still get the **org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable** exception. 
This is the latest version of the code;

```
//selecting student information tab
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.mat-tab-labels>div:nth-child(2)")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
//enter lastname

// try {
//       new 
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("ms-text- 
field[placeholder='GENERAL.FIELD.LAST_NAME']"))).click();
//  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ms-text- 
field[placeholder='GENERAL.FIELD.LAST_NAME']")).sendKeys("Abuzer");
// } catch (Exception e){}

 WebElement lname = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ms-text-field[@formcontrolname='lastName']"));
 lname.click();
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 lname.sendKeys("John");`
```

I am also sharing the commented parts of what have not worked for me.

Comment: Did you check the presence of `iframe` ? In your last test with "Xpath", what happens if you target the `input` element instead of the `ms-text-field` ? Something like : `WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//ms-text-field[@formcontrolname='lastName']/input"))).click();`

Comment: it worked! Thank you for the help. I guess my use of both css selectors and xpath locators at the same time messed it up. I just used xpath to both click() and sendkeys() methods.

Comment: Nice, well played. I've added my comment as an answer for users who could face the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the presence of iframe ?

In your last test with "Xpath", what happens if you target the input element instead of the ms-text-field ? Something like :

`WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//ms-text-field[@formcontrolname='lastName']/input"))).click();`